# how to add cloudinary parameters to upload plugin in Trumbowyg

Tags: javascript, jquery, cloudinary, dropzone, trumbowyg

I am using the trumbowyg editor in my project. From the documentation, I know that I can use the following code to set the image upload content of the editor.

```
$('#editor')
.trumbowyg({
    btns: ['upload'],
    plugins: {
        // Add imagur parameters to upload plugin for demo purposes
        upload: {
            serverPath: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
            fileFieldName: 'image',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Client-ID xxxxxxxxxxxx'
            },
            urlPropertyName: 'data.link'
        }
    }
});
```

this works fine with `imgur` but I want to use `cloudinary` server instead of `imgur`.

could anyone please guide what I have to do with `plugins:{}` when using `cloudinary`?

also I'm using `dropzone.js` with `cloudinary` to upload image and this is also working properly.
here is dropzone function code:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = true;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.getElementById('image-upload'), {
  clickable: "#image-upload #btn-add",
  uploadMultiple: false,
  autoProcessQueue: true,
  acceptedFiles:'.jpg,.png,.jpeg,.gif',
  parallelUploads: 10,
  maxFilesize: 9,
  maxFiles: 10,
  url: 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/demo_project/image/upload',
  addedfile: function(file) {
    // console.log(file);
    new Noty({
      type: 'success',
      text: "Uploading...",
      timeout: false
    }).show();
    // myDropzone.processQueue();
  },
  success: function(file, response){
    new Noty({
      type: 'success',
      text: "Uploaded!",
      killer: true
    }).show();
    newImageArray.push({
      public_id: response.public_id,
      url: response.url,
      secure_url: response.secure_url
    });
    newImageArrayJSON = JSON.stringify(newImageArray);
    $imageStorage.val(newImageArrayJSON)
    $("#image-upload .image").html('<img src="' + response.secure_url + '">')
    $("#image-upload #btn-add").hide();
    $("#image-upload #btn-remove").show();
  }
});
myDropzone.on('sending', function (file, xhr, formData) {
  formData.append('api_key', 112233445566778);
  formData.append('timestamp', Date.now() / 1000 | 0);
  formData.append('upload_preset', 'mypreset');
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise starting with the following basic implementation which I tested and worked for me:

```
$('#editor').trumbowyg({
    btns: ['upload'],
    plugins: {
        upload: {
            serverPath: 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/demo_project/image/upload',
            fileFieldName: 'file',
            urlPropertyName: 'data.secure_url',
            data: [
                {name: 'api_key', value: '112233445566778'},
                {name: 'timestamp', value: Date.now() / 1000 | 0},
                {name: 'upload_preset', value: 'mypreset'}
            ],
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You can log in to your Cloudinary account and modify your upload preset to restrict uploads based on different conditions, the same as you do with `dropzone.js`, for example to only allow uploads of specific formats etc.

Comment: this working almost 80% perfectly but this is not showing image after upload, because docs says.

It must save this image, then return a JSON response like that:


{
    success: true, // Must be false if upload fails
    url: 'https://example.com/myimage.jpg'
}

but my response is:

{bytes: 73201
format: "png"
secure_url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/demo_project/image/upload/v1545768672/Screenshot_from_2018-04-14_01-17-50_ksol8m.png"
tags: []
url: "http://res.cloudinary.com/demo_project/image/upload/v1545768672/Screenshot_from_2018-04-14_01-17-50_ksol8m.png"
}